# Horizontally center scroll position to visible portion of container with active link in view

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I'm looking for a way position the `scrollLeft` in a way where the left and right of the scroll container is center with my active link. Right now I found a way to get the scrollLeft to center to the link itself. If it makes more sense, I need the space to the left and right of the active link to be equal.

```js
// MODIFIED FROM https://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/6bfuspkq/


jQuery.fn.scrollCenter = function(elem) {

  // this = #timepicker
  // elem = .active

  var active = jQuery(this).find(elem); // find the active element
  //var activeWidth = active.width(); // get active width
  var activeWidth = active.width() / 2; // get active width center

  //alert(activeWidth)

  //var pos = jQuery('#timepicker .active').position().left; //get left position of active li
  // var pos = jQuery(elem).position().left; //get left position of active li
  //var pos = jQuery(this).find(elem).position().left; //get left position of active li
  var pos = active.position().left + activeWidth; //get left position of active li + center position
  var elpos = jQuery(this).scrollLeft(); // get current scroll position
  var elW = jQuery(this).width(); //get div width
  //var divwidth = jQuery(elem).width(); //get div width
  pos = pos + elpos - elW / 2; // for center position if you want adjust then change this

  $(this).scrollLeft(pos);
};

// http://podzic.com/wp-content/plugins/podzic/include/js/podzic.js
jQuery.fn.scrollCenterORI = function(elem, speed) {
  jQuery(this).animate({
    scrollLeft: jQuery(this).scrollLeft() - jQuery(this).offset().left + jQuery(elem).offset().left
  }, speed == undefined ? 1000 : speed);
  return this;
};

$("#viewContainer").scrollCenter(".active");
```

```css
html,
body,
div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
}

#viewContainer {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 90px;
}

.page {
  text-align: center;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="viewContainer">
    <div class="page " id="viewLeft2">I am very left.</div>
    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>
    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>
    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>
    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>
    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>
    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>
    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>
    <div class="page active" id="">Text page</div>

    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>
    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>
    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>

    <div class="page" id="">Text page</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Meaning, if last div.page is active than you want to show in center (also scrollbar in center) by adding more space on right?

Comment: It would apply mainly to the ones in the middle. The left/right ends would just scroll to the active link's center.

Comment: This is great by the way